# Object not centering

Tags: sculpting

Have a problem with centering my object for sculpt mode. I have modeled my character with a mirror modifier and i have him centered at the Z axis. Now if i select my char and click cursor to selected and then set origin to 3d cursor, the center point is a bit to the right of the characters center. I had to fix this by manually placing the 3d cursor in the center of the grid to make sculpting possible. Does anybody know what has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

When you select a model and tell it to place the cursor at its center, the cursor does not take into account any modifiers (such as your mirror modifier), and therefore it goes to the center of the vertices you have selected, as seen here:

[image: Cursor to Selected]

Then, if you place your origin at the cursor, your mirror modifier will use the origin as your axis point:

[image]

So, if your mirror modifier uses the origin as its mirror axis, then all you need to do is place the origin at the point you want to mirror from. This can be done several ways, but the most precise would be to select a single vertex where you want your mirror to occur, and set the cursor to that point (Set cursor to selected):

[image: Single Vertex Selected]

Then set this point as your origin, the same way as per usual, and your mirror modifier will then use it as the mirror axis:

[image: Origin Set to Vertex]

It is a simple mistake to make, and thankfully an easy one to fix.
Hopefully that helps explain the issue you faced.

Comment: Yes and no. I forgot to mention the mirror modifier had been applied already when I started sculpting so the center should have been in the center of the object, right? I am suspecting that I might have moved the complete object a bit to the left when modelling. Could that result in that the center point is a bit to the right?

Comment: I think the center is still reliant on the origin point... could you upload a .blend file for us to experiment with?